# Unity 5 движение по кругу через поворот

Tags: c#, unity3d

Тело двигается по следующему алгоритму. Сначала выбирается случайный угол, на который происходит поворот тела, затем задается Vector2.up и тело летит в направлении поворота. Как сделать чтобы тело двигалось по кругу? Знаю, что необходимо использовать тригонометрические функции, но как конкретно - не знаю.

Comment: ...кругу какого радиуса?

Comment: Нужно относительно какого-то центра? или просто в какой-то момент взял и полетел по кругу? по часовой или против часовой стрелки?

Comment: Можно каждый тик поворачивать тело на какой-то градус и сдвигать его вперед по оси x например. Или можно использовать уравнение окружности x(t) = r*sin(t), y(t) = r*cos(t), меняя t получим координаты объекта в определенный момент времени

Comment: @Алексей  Благодарю за уточнения! По факту - чтобы при вызове метода тело полетело по кругу радиуса R, или например, по синусоиде, т.е. полкруга сделало - и в другую сторону. Так что необходимы все варианты. Если допустим вызвал метод через InvokeRepeating(1, 1), что и как должно меняться каждую секунду? Как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вспоминаем геометрию. Уравнение окружности имеет вид:

```
(x - a)² + (x - b)² = R²
```

где

`a, b` - координаты центра окружности

`R` - радиус окружности

Уравнение окружности радиуса R с центром в начале координат:

```
x² + y² = R²
```

Это поможет нам узнать переменные в другом представлении окружности: в параметрическом уравнении:

```
x = R * cos(alpha) + a 
y = R * sin(alpha) + b
```

в центре координат:

```
x = R * cos(alpha)
y = R * sin(alpha)
```

Видим знакомые данные и еще дополнительную: `alpha`. Думаю понятно, что это угол.
Меняем угол альфа и получаем движение по окружности.

Все это переносим в Unity.

Итак:

```
public float angle = 0; // угол 
public float radius = 0.5f; // радиус
public bool isCircle = false; // условие движения по кругу
```

Допустим в какой-то момент времени нужно, чтоб объект начал движение по кругу, а значит нужно изменять постепенно угол и передавать значение в координаты. 
Угол можно менять например в `Update`, который будет каждый фрейм вызываться. Тогда получится простая формула:

```
void Update () {
    if (isCircle) {
        angle += Time.deltaTime; // меняется плавно значение угла

        var x = Mathf.Cos (angle * speed) * radius;
        var y = Mathf.Sin (angle * speed) * radius;
        transform.position = new Vector2(x, y);
    }
}
```

Когда нужно прекратить движение по кругу, выставляем  `isCircle` в false и обнуляем угол `angle = 0;`

Всё.

Для движения вокруг какого-то центра не забываем добавить это условие в координаты. Например центр с координатами `1, 1.5`; Формула будет например такая:

```
var x = Mathf.Cos (angle * speed) * radius;
var y = Mathf.Sin (angle * speed) * radius;
transform.position = new Vector2(x, y) + new Vector2(1, 1.5);
```

---

По часовой или против часовой?

Тут всё банально просто. Нужно одну из координат умножить дополнительно на -1.
Если умножить X, то движение пойдет так, как будто находитесь на отметке 180°

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если умножить Y, то с отметки 0°:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я ничего не путаю))

Вот банальное и в очень сыром виде движение тела вперед, а при изменении параметра `isCircle` в `true` летит против часовой стрелки ровно с того места, где находится (для этого в формуле еще один параметр `new Vector2(radius, 0)` для компенсации направления движения).

```js
using UnityEngine;

public class Testy: MonoBehaviour {
  public float angle = 0;

  public float speed = 1;
  public float radius = 0.5f;
  public bool isCircle = false;

  // запоминать свое нахождение и делать его центром окружности
  public Vector2 cachedCenter;

  void Update() {
    if (isCircle) {
      angle += Time.deltaTime;
      var x = Mathf.Cos(angle * speed) * radius;
      var y = Mathf.Sin(angle * speed) * radius;
      transform.position = new Vector2(x, y) + cachedCenter - new Vector2(radius, 0);
    } else {
      angle = 0;
      cachedCenter = transform.position;
      var x = transform.position.x;
      var y = transform.position.y;
      x += 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;

      transform.position = new Vector2(x, y);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Ну и по поводу движения по синусоиде. Тут немного по-другому. По одной оси мы просто движемся, а по другой, так сказать "вихляем".

Я попробую просто написать две формулы, попробуйте разобраться с ними сами)))

**1)** Движение вперед, "вихляет" вниз-вверх:

```js
using UnityEngine;

public class Testy2: MonoBehaviour {

  public float MoveSpeed = 0.5f;
  public float frequency = 3.0f; // Скорость виляния по синусоиде
  public float magnitude = 0.5f; // Размер синусоиды (радиус, по сути..можно заменить на "R")

  private Vector3 axis;
  private Vector3 pos;

  void Start() {
    pos = transform.position;
    axis = transform.up;
  }

  void Update() {
    pos += transform.right * Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed;
    transform.position = pos + axis * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * magnitude;
  }
}
```

**2)** Движение вверх, "вихляет" влево-вправо:

```js
using UnityEngine;

public class Testy2: MonoBehaviour {

  public float MoveSpeed = 0.5f;

  public float frequency = 3.0f; // Скорость виляния по синусоиде
  public float magnitude = 0.5f; // Размер синусоиды (радиус, по сути..можно заменить на "R")

  private Vector3 axis;
  private Vector3 pos;

  void Start() {
    pos = transform.position;
    axis = transform.right;
  }

  void Update() {
    pos += transform.up * Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed;
    transform.position = pos + axis * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * frequency) * magnitude;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спустя уже 2 года хочу немного подправить ответ, вдруг кому пригодиться. Чтобы получить скорость, нужно, грубо говоря, замедлять и ускорять время, то есть так: angle = angle + speed * Time.deltaTime;
Если, мы находим косинус из произведения угла и скорости, то как бы перемещаем объект, а скорость при этом не меняется.