# Круговое перемещение unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Каким образом можно реализовать перемещение unity 2D объекта из точки А в точку Б круговым движением так, чтобы это было максимально коротко (то есть если по часовой короче, то по часовой стрелке, если против, то против)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что я хочу реализовать

Comment: Возьмите формулу дуги..... высчитываете две длины и выбираете ту, что короче

Comment: это понятно, но каким образом плавно перемещать по дуге

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/533735/191482

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Unity 5 движение по кругу через поворот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533735/unity-5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82)

Comment: Вижу хотелку.... а в чем вопрос? где именно возникла проблема?

Comment: угол в градусах или радианах. Я это использовал и в итоге при увеличении угла на 60 градусов оно совершает движение в несколько кругов почему-то, а не на 60 градусов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я бы использовал бы движение по сплайну и не морочил бы себе голову со всякими движениями по формулах в коде.

Достаточно легко ищется по запросу "unity move spline path". Есть как платные ассеты для этого так и бесплатные скрипты из интернета.

Например: Bézier Path Creator

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/b-zier-path-creator-136082

Comment: Благодарю, хороший ответ. Вопрос исчерпан полностью